# Getting Variable does not exist: Time in an apex method in salesforce

Tags: apex

I wrote a test class for my Date & Time class.

So I have this inside my code method:

Date myDate = Date.today();

Time myTime = Time.hour();

For date it's working fine but for time getting error.

Comment: Please include the error message as that can help answer the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the current time just do

```
Time currentHour = Datetime.now().time();
```

Note that there is also a `timeGmt` method, which you might need if you're running into time zone issues. Also note the `getTime` method returns completely different data (a `Long` representing the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT).

As for why you got the error, if you look at the `Time` [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_time.htm), you will see that the `hour` method just returns an `Integer` which represents the hour component of a specific `Time` instance (it's not a `static` method).

```
Time myTime = Time.newInstance(18, 30, 2, 20);
myTime = myTime.addHours(2);
Integer myHour = myTime.hour();
System.assertEquals(myHour, 20);
```